# DataTables with Rails- Show and Hide Columns Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, datatables

I installed the DataTables gem for my Rails app and got started by following [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast). Everything worked fine.

My goal was to allow users of my app to hide and show columns, so I read [this guide](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/show_hide.html).

I copied the initialization javascript from that page, translated it to coffeescript at http://js2coffee.org, and pasted the following into my app/assets/javascripts/drivers.js.coffee file:

```
fnShowHide = (iCol) ->
  oTable = $("#drivers").dataTable()
  bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis iCol, (if bVis then false else true)
$(document).ready ->
  $("#drivers").dataTable
    sScrollY: "200px"
    bPaginate: false
```

Then returning to the [DataTables guide](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/show_hide.html), I viewed the source code of the "Toggle column" links, and found this: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(0);">Toggle column 1<br></a>`.

So I pasted that into my app/views/drivers/index.html.erb file, resulting in the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(0);">Toggle column 1<br></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(1);">Toggle column 2<br></a>

<table id="drivers" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @drivers.each do |driver| %> 
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to(driver.last_name, driver) %></td>
      <td><%= driver.first_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I go to the site, the links are showing, but they don't work. Since I'm new to Rails, javascript, and programming in general, I assume I'm leaving out some obvious detail.

Comment: Did you include the DataTables JS file(s) ?
Also, when working with Javascript, always have an eye on your browser's console.

Comment: You mean in application.css and application.js? If so, I did.

Comment: Well, I abandoned dataTables and came up with a solution inspired by the code [here](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/872753-show-hide-columns-table).  And [here's my variation](http://jsfiddle.net/jbswetnam/SRvSq/).

Comment: Glad you made it. Sorry I could not provide more help, the code that you posted did not reveal any obvious error.

Comment: No problem. I learned more this way, anyway.